# cps mismatch when sending a slack message in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am calling this function from a declarative pipeline in the post always stage:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
@NonCPS
def call(){
    String path = "C:\\Users\\tests"
    String jsonFileToRead = new File(path).listFiles().findAll { it.name.endsWith(".json") }
        .sort { -it.lastModified() }?.head()
    JsonSlurper jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    Map data = jsonSlurper.parse(new File(jsonFileToRead))
    Map testResults = [:]
    int totalTests = data.results.size()
    int totalFailures = 0
    int totalSuccess = 0
    def results = []

    //Map test names and results from json file
    for (int i = 0; i < data.results.size(); i++) {
        testResults.put(i, [data['results'][i]['TestName'], data['results'][i]['result']])
    }

    //Iterate through the map and send to slack test name and results and then a summary of the total tests, failures and success
    for (test in testResults.values()){
        String testName =  test[0]
        String testResult = test[1]
        String msg = "Test: " + testName + " Result: " + testResult
        if(testResult == "fail")
        {
            totalFailures++ 
            println msg
            try {
                slackSend color : "danger", message: "${msg}", channel: '#somechannel'
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                error "Caught ${e.toString()}" 
            }   
        }
        else if(testResult == "pass")
        {
            totalSuccess++
            println msg
            try {
                slackSend color : "good", message: "${msg}", channel: '#somechannel'
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                error "Caught ${e.toString()}" 
            }            
        }
        else
        {
            println "Unknown test result: " + testResult
        }
    }
    def resultsSummary = "Total Tests: " + totalTests + " Total Failures: " + totalFailures + " Total Success: " + totalSuccess
    slackSend color : "good", message: "${resultsSummary}", channel: '#somechannel'
    println resultsSummary
```

but I keep getting this error, even though I am using the @NonCPS. I am bit confused as if I comment out the 3 lines where I call the slackSend functionality everything goes fine and I get in the console output the right messages and the pipeline finishes succesfully, but if I run it like it is I get this error even if I just try to send the summary and comment out the other 2 slackSend:

```
13:53:23  [Pipeline] echo
13:53:23  Test: triggers_attackMove Result: pass
13:53:23  [Pipeline] slackSend
13:53:23  Slack Send Pipeline step running, values are - baseUrl: <empty>, teamDomain: forgottenempires, channel: #test_harness_logs_phoenix, color: good, botUser: true, tokenCredentialId: Slack_bot_test, notifyCommitters: false, iconEmoji: :goose, username: Jenkins Wizard, timestamp: <empty>
13:53:23  [Pipeline] error
13:53:24  [Pipeline] }
13:53:24  [Pipeline] // script
13:53:24  Error when executing always post condition:
13:53:24  hudson.AbortException: Caught CpsCallableInvocation{methodName=slackSend, call=com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsFunction@149776fc, receiver=null, arguments=[org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL$ThreadTaskImpl@25def8]}
13:53:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ErrorStep$Execution.run(ErrorStep.java:64)
13:53:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ErrorStep$Execution.run(ErrorStep.java:51)
13:53:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousStepExecution.start(SynchronousStepExecution.java:37)
13:53:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:322)
13:53:24    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
enter code here
....
```

I tried to take the slackSend functionality to another function with the @NonCPS decorator and call it from within the function but I keep getting the same error, and honestly I am quiet lost a this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slackSend` is a pipeline step and as such can't be called from `@NonCPS` context. There are only a few exceptions like `echo`, that work from `@NonCPS` context. See [Use of Pipeline steps from @NonCPS](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/#use-of-pipeline-steps-fromnoncps) for details.

My approach in such cases is to remove `@NonCPS` from the function that calls the step(s) and move only the code that actually requires `@NonCPS` into separate `@NonCPS` functions. In your case that's propably just the code that uses the `File` and `JsonSlurper` classes.

Also, we need to make sure that any data returned by the `@NonCPS` functions is **serializable**. `JsonSlurper` returns a `LazyMap` that isn't. As OP commented, the easiest solution is to use `JsonSlurperClassic` instead, which returns a regular, serializable `Map` (or a `List` in case the root is an array).

```groovy
@NonCPS
Map readData(){
    String path = "C:\\Users\\tests"
    String jsonFileToRead = new File(path).listFiles().findAll { it.name.endsWith(".json") }
        .sort { -it.lastModified() }?.head()
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurperClassic()
    return jsonSlurper.parse(new File(jsonFileToRead))
}

// Note: Must not be @NonCPS because pipeline steps are called!
def call(){
    Map data = readData()
    Map testResults = [:]
    int totalTests = data.results.size()
    int totalFailures = 0
    int totalSuccess = 0
    def results = []

    //Map test names and results from json file
    for (int i = 0; i < data.results.size(); i++) {
        testResults.put(i, [data['results'][i]['TestName'], data['results'][i]['result']])
    }

    //Iterate through the map and send to slack test name and results and then a summary of the total tests, failures and success
    for (test in testResults.values()){
        String testName =  test[0]
        String testResult = test[1]
        String msg = "Test: " + testName + " Result: " + testResult
        if(testResult == "fail")
        {
            totalFailures++ 
            println msg
            try {
                slackSend color : "danger", message: "${msg}", channel: '#somechannel'
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                error "Caught ${e.toString()}" 
            }   
        }
        else if(testResult == "pass")
        {
            totalSuccess++
            println msg
            try {
                slackSend color : "good", message: "${msg}", channel: '#somechannel'
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                error "Caught ${e.toString()}" 
            }            
        }
        else
        {
            println "Unknown test result: " + testResult
        }
    }
    def resultsSummary = "Total Tests: " + totalTests + " Total Failures: " + totalFailures + " Total Success: " + totalSuccess
    slackSend color : "good", message: "${resultsSummary}", channel: '#somechannel'
    println resultsSummary
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but after trying your solution I keep getting this error
'''20:55:59  Error when executing always post condition:
20:55:59  hudson.AbortException: Caught java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap'''

Comment: @jesusfernandez The docs say about `LazyMap`: _"This maps only builds once you ask for a key for the first time."_. Try to use its [`putAll()`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/apache/groovy/json/internal/LazyMap.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) method to copy it into a regular map (see modified code).

Comment: Thanks @zett42 I sorted it out using JsonSlurperClassic instead of JsonSlurper

Comment: @jesusfernandez This sounds like a better solution. Can you please modify my answer to use `JsonSlurperClassic`? Thx!